# Node restful api, File upload and save file names in database before post

Tags: node.js, rest, express, node-rest-client

I have develop a node restful api. i need to upload some image files and save file names in to the database. how  do it. this is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) 
  {
    callback(null, Date.now('nano') +         path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',2);

// Models
var Car = require('../models/car');

// Routes
Car.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);

// before file uplod part
Car.before('post',function(req,res,next)
{
    var car_photos = [];
    upload(req,res,function(err) 
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) 
            {
                car_photos.push(req.files[i]['filename']);
            }
        }
    });
     req.body.car_photos = car_photos;
     next();
});
Car.register(router,'/car');
module.exports = router;
```

This car_photos array is null. how i save this array my database. please help .

```
Car.before('post',function(req,res,next)
{
    var car_photos = [];
    upload(req,res,function(err) 
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) 
            {
                car_photos.push(req.files[i]['filename']);
            }
        }
    });
     req.body.car_photos = car_photos;
     next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

req.body.car_photos = car_photos;
next();

these lines should be in the upload function call back. In the else block after the for loop.

Comment: Is it possible post full answer with models itself

Answer (score 0):

This example applies for anyone using the library node-restful
https://github.com/baugarten/node-restful

For the model add a field with:

```
car_photos: Array
```

---

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) 
  {
    callback(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('car_photos',2);

// Models
var Car = require('../models/car');

// Routes
Car.methods(['get','put','post','delete']);

// before file uplod part
Car.before('post',function(req,res,next)
{
    var car_photos = [];
    upload(req,res,function(err) 
    {
        if(err) 
        {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) 
            {
                car_photos.push(req.files[i]['filename']);
            }
            req.body.car_photos = car_photos;
            next();
        }
    });
});
Car.register(router,'/car');
module.exports = router;
```